# Error printing on network printer hp laserjet4200 in ubuntu 14.10

Tags: printing, 14.10

I have recently upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10. I was using network printer HP Laserjet 4200 on 14.04 without any problem.

After the upgrade, on both my laptop and desktop computers, I am unable to print any document. The printer has started printing blank pages with one line printed on first page:

%!PS-adobe-3.0
%Produced by poppler pdftop version: 0.26.5

Comment: I'm certainly glad you posted this.  A friend of mine for whom I'd installed 12.04 had recently upgraded his installation to 14.10 and then complained that his HP Laserget *4* was no longer accepting commands over the network.  He even brought  his setup to my house to see if I could figure it out.  Now that I've seen this, I wish I'd tried to find his network printer using my 12.04 installation.

I provided him a USB to centronics adapter cable so he can turn a raspberry pi into a print server for it.

Comment: No one to provide solution? Please help... My colleagues are making fun of Ubuntu as I have to use their Windows based computers to print my documents.

Comment: The joke will be on your colleagues when their windows computers divulge their passwords to hundreds of hackers.  Perhaps you can later teach them the error of their ways, but for now we have to solve this printer issue.  For starters I would advise you to, assuming you have not, go into printers and delete your current printer definition and try to persuade it to relocate and redefine your old printer afresh.  Of course if you have already done this, please let me know and I will resume research.

Comment: you may want to reinstall the drivers manually first.  Here is the link I found.  http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

Comment: @gropyge Thank you for considering my problem. I already tried removing and adding the printer again. Facing same problem after installing new version of hplip.

Answer (score 2):

My problem is solved by selecting **cups** from the drivers list instead of **Postscrip**